# How to listen multiple domain names with same port?

Tags: django, networking, nginx, webserver, port

I have multiple domain names and multiple Django applications for each domain in my server. I pointed all domains to my server's IP. I want to run Django servers for each domain and map these servers and domain names with Nginx.

The problem is when I want to bind example.com:80 as host:port pair setting in my Django settings file, if there is an instance running on 127.0.0.1:80 it can't bind that address. Therefore I had to use different ports for each domain and map example.com:80 to 127.0.0.1:XXXX in Nginx.

I want to automate this process but since I had to use different ports for each domain, I have to find free ports when I host new sites. Is there any way to bind servers directly to domain.com:80 and map domain.com to internal Django server that listens domain.com:80 with Nginx for each domain?

Comment: You can simple handle all your domains with a single nginx.
Run your django apps in uwsgi or gunicorn and configure nginx to deliver the static stuff.
I'm unsure what you really want to accomplish? Do you want a Django deployment tool?
I've I got you right you want to run the built in Django server in production? I don't thing that's a good idea.

Comment: @kelvan Actually I use nginx & gunicorn & django but I didn't mentioned gunicorn in the question because I think it doesn't make any difference. What I want to do is to run multiple Django applications in a server and configure the nginx to proxy domains to django servers. The problem is I want to automate this process and I don't know which address I should bind with gunicorn. If the ip address that I bind is 127.0.0.1 than I have to find a free port when I want to host a new website but it doesn't seems like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on one server you can use different unix sockets instead of addresses. This way you have control over the names you generate in your automation tool and aren't relying on available ports. 
If you are using more than one server then I don't believe there are more options than using a pool of ports and connecting to the next available one from this pool

Comment: I didn't know unix sockets can be used this way. Thanks for the advice!